# Problem with Formatting User-defined Types with fmt library

Tags: fmt

I faced a problem for formatting a user-defined type and ended up with this simple example based on fmt documentation.

```
struct point_double {
    double x, y;

    operator const char*() const {
        return nullptr;
    }
};

namespace fmt {
template <>
struct formatter<point_double> {
    template <typename ParseContext>
    constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx) {
        return ctx.begin();
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const point_double& p, FormatContext& ctx) {
        return format_to(ctx.out(), "({:.1f}, {:.1f})", p.x, p.y);
    }
};
}  // namespace fmt

void foo() {
    point_double p = {1, 2};
    fmt::print("{}\n", p);
}
```

Calling `foo` will crash because the user-defined formatter is not used. Instead `fmt::print` will use the default string formatter and crash as the operator returns `nullptr`.
Is there a way to go around this issue? I'm using fmt 5.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have both an implicit conversion to `const char*` and a `formatter` specialization ({fmt} will now give you a compile-time error), because `const char*` is already formattable. If you have control over `point_double`, an easy solution is to make the conversion operator explicit which is a good idea in general. Otherwise you can wrap `point_double` in another type and provide a `formatter` specialization for that.